# Background colour of remaining flags/close vote count

Tags: support, design, flagging, voting

Whenever I choose to cast vote on a question or flag a post, the count of remaining votes/flags for the day is shown besides the button.

[image]

[image]

I have observed that the background colour of the box shown behind the number is sometimes Orange and sometimes Blue. What does the colour signify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colour helps highlight the difference between the flag count and the vote count. It helps distinguish with a quick glance which of the two figures it represents without reading the word beside the number; it's orange for flags and blue for votes.